# Replacing multiple different strings in various columns with 1 and mutating a new column with counts in dplyr

Tags: r, count, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 100 columns of different strings.

Example:

```
id  Disease1 Disease2 Disease3
01  disease1  NA      disease3
02  NA       disease2 NA
03  disease1 disease2 NA
```

How can I convert different values in multiple columns into 1 and then mutate a new column, counting total number of 1 in specific columns (maybe in columns 22:65) or even better `starts_with()`.

Desired output

```
id  Disease1 Disease2 Disease3 Total_diseases
01  1        NA       1        2
02  NA       1        NA       1
03  1        1        NA       2
```

Comment: can you add some output which you wish to see ?

Comment: @SametSökel, updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('id  Disease1 Disease2 Disease3
01  disease1  NA      disease3
02  NA       disease2 NA
03  disease1 disease2 NA'),header=T)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(Total_diseases=sum(!is.na(across(Disease1:Disease3)))) %>%
ungroup
```

it checks from Disease1 to Disease3 with `accross` function.

output;

```
     id Disease1 Disease2 Disease3 Total_diseases
  <int> <fct>    <fct>    <fct>             <int>
1     1 disease1 NA       disease3              2
2     2 NA       disease2 NA                    1
3     3 disease1 disease2 NA                    2
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your time and efforts. I saw similar, but could fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Use `across` to change the non-empty values to 1 and `rowSums` to sum them row wise.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Disease'), ~+(. != ''))) %>%
  mutate(Total_disease = rowSums(select(.,starts_with('Disease')), na.rm = TRUE))

#  id Disease1 Disease2 Disease3 Total_disease
#1  1        1       NA        1             2
#2  2       NA        1       NA             1
#3  3        1        1       NA             2
```