# Replacing multiple different strings in various columns with 1 and mutating a new column with counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I did this in R with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68956536/replacing-multiple-different-strings-in-various-columns-with-1-and-mutating-a-ne), but switched to Python and still do not see a good answer.

I have a dataframe with 200 columns of different strings and numbers.

Example:

```
Name  Gender Disease1 Disease2 Disease3
Joe   Male   disease1 NA       disease3
Ben   Male   NA       disease2 NA
Chloe Female disease1 disease2 NA
```

How can I convert different `Disease` values in multiple columns into 1 and then mutate a new column, counting total number of 1 in specific columns (maybe in columns 22:65).

Desired output

```
Name  Gender Disease1 Disease2 Disease3 Total_diseases
Joe   Male   disease1 NA       disease3 2
Ben   Male   NA       disease2 NA       1
Chloe Female disease1 disease2 NA       2
```

I want to have a new column `Total_diseases`, where all text values (now converted to 1) are summarized. So if one person has 10 diseases, it will show up in this mutated column. Hope it answers your questions.

Comment: It seems you  just want to check if values are null ? `df.notnull()` ?

Comment: I do not think so, I need a new column with a number of counts. And I need for specific columns from-to, not the whole dataframe

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker what you want to do with the "Disease" columns is unclear, please elaborate if what I did in my answer is not what you want.

Comment: Your question is not clear , please elaborate more

Comment: @mozway, replied and updated

Comment: No, I want to sum the count of 1 in the selected columns and mutate a new column for this.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker the question is, do you need the dummies? If yes you can follow anky's comment. In you only need the total count, just leave the "Disease" columns intact and use `df.nunique(axis=1)` (see my answer)

Comment: If anything is not what you'd expect, please provide a counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set index on `id` then use `notna()` to get those entries not null and change them to 1 with `.astype(int)`.  Then filter `Disease*` columns by `.filter()` and `sum` on `axis=1` for the count on each row:

```
df_out = df.set_index('id').notna().astype(int).reset_index()

df_out['Total_diseases'] = df_out.filter(like='Disease').sum(axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
print(df_out)

   id  Disease1  Disease2  Disease3  Total_diseases
0   1         1         0         1               2
1   2         0         1         0               1
2   3         1         1         0               2
```

### Edit:

If you want to specify range of columns by number, you can use `.iloc` e.g. use   `df_out.iloc[:, 10:30]` and use `df_out.iloc[:, 10:30].sum(axis=1)` for summing these columns.

### Edit 2

According to the updated sample input and desired output, and you mentioned you want to quote the range of columns by column numbers instead of by filtering similar column labels as in the solution above (probably the real diseases names have no common pattern), you can use `.iloc` instead,  as follows:

```
df['Total_diseases'] = df.iloc[:, 2:5].notna().sum(axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

    Name  Gender  Disease1  Disease2  Disease3  Total_diseases
0    Joe    Male  disease1       NaN  disease3               2
1    Ben    Male       NaN  disease2       NaN               1
2  Chloe  Female  disease1  disease2       NaN               2
```

Comment: Thanks. How to do the same for specific columns - between 10:30?

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker  You can use `.iloc` e.g.  `df_out.iloc[:, 10:30].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: I have no idea why, but it changes everything in my dataframe to 0 and 1, even values in columns, which I do not want to change

Comment: @anky, I have 200 columns, I am not sure how explain it better

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker  You don't want those values change to 1 when not NA ?

Comment: @SeaBean, apologize, a made a better example adding columns for understanding.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker   See my further edit above.

Comment: Works, thanks for your time, and so much efforts

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker  Welcome!   But as anky said, probably better to craft better sample data at the question adhering to your real needs.  Avoid making big changes to the questions afterwards because of finding out later that the initial requirement is not exactly what you want!   Anyway, happy programming and have a nice weekend :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the "Total_diseases" column, you don't need to change anything to the original columns:

```
df = df.set_index('id')
df['Total_diseases'] = df.nunique(axis=1)
```

If there are initially columns other than 'Disease':

```
cols = df.filter(like='Disease').columns
df['Total_diseases'] = df[cols].nunique(axis=1)
```

This here is just to change the original columns to one for non NA values:

```
cols = df.filter(like='Disease').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].where(df[cols].isna(), 1)
```

output:

```
   Disease1 Disease2 Disease3  Total_diseases
id                                           
1         1      NaN        1               2
2       NaN        1      NaN               1
3         1        1      NaN               2
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your solution :( What is goes first? Which part? Your output seems correct, but for me it counts everything in the dataframe, not only `Disease` columns.

Comment: It counts everything as there are only 'Disease' columns initially. I'll add an update

Comment: Thanks. How to do the same for specific columns between 10:30? If I do for disease column, it gives me a wrong number, not what I am expecting.

Comment: apologize, a made a better example adding columns for understanding.

Comment: Then the second block of code in my answer should work: `df['Total_diseases'] = df[df.filter(like='Disease').columns].nunique(axis=1)`

Comment: Works, thanks for your time and so much efforts